# jQuery PicNet Table Filter specify column programmatically

Tags: jquery, tablefilter

Wondering if anyone has experience with PicNet table filter plugin for jQuery.

This is what I did for generating the filter for me table.

$('#tableName').tableFilter();

I am wondering if there is a way to not generate filter textbox or dropdown  for particular columns?

thanks

Comment: not sure but try something like `$('#tableName:not(.my_tag)').tableFilter();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

End up modifying the getFilterStr method in the js file to not generate any html controls for a specific "filter-type". in my case i use "none".

Answer (score 3):

In case anybody has the same problem,

filter='false' will do the trick.

Regards,
pepebe

Comment: For anyone still wondering: this should be an attribute on the TH tag. Good luck ;-)